# How to Insert Characters into MaskedEditExtender with SendKeys?

Tags: vb.net, selenium, internet-explorer-11

I created a TextBox and associated a MaskedEditExtender with Mask="999" to the TextBox.

When I manually attempt to enter alpha characters like "bad" into the TextBox the MaskedEditExtender prevents the alpha from being entered. That is expected behavior.

When I insert alpha characters, like "Bad", using Selenium SendKeys, the "Bad" characters are inserted into the TextBox.

I'm using IE 11, Selenium InternetExplorerDriver 3.4, and Windows 7.

I know InternetExplorerDriver versions 3.51, 3.7, and 3.8 are available. However, those versions insert double characters into textboxes. For example, if I want to insert "Test" then "TTeesstt" gets inserted into the textbox. So I downgraded to 3.4.

Thanks, Ed